# Logging into subdomain with the same credentials in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, subdomain

I have a portal say 'portal.mysite.com'. I have another portal say 'login.mysite.com'. Could someone tell me how I could use the same login credentials to login into the subdomain?

Thanks for sharing your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this short article useful: http://forums.asp.net/t/1023838.aspx